# How to fix "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null" in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to create a script that will go through a .sql file and replace one string with another string and create a new file. I have gotten the script to allow me to select a file, but I have not been able to get the replace part of the script to work without getting an error.

I have gone through the code line by line, but I do not see why the parameter is not being set.

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.Filter = "SQL File (*.sql)| *.sql"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
}

$inputfile = Get-FileName "E:\OneDrive\Work"
$inputdata = Get-Content -Path $inputfile


((Get-Content $inputdata -replace 'DEFINER=`root`@`%`','DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`')) | Set-Content ($intputdata + '_fixed.sql')
```

The expectation is that the file that is chosen from the popup window will have the string replaced and a new file with the correct string will be created.

Comment: `Get-FileName` doesn't return anything. It just shows the dialog. You specifically pipe it to Null. I might also suggest `Out-GridView`  which appears to do the same thing

Comment: as Matt pointed out, the problem is that **_you are sending the selected file info to $Null_** ... so fix that by removing the command to throw away the selected item info ... [*grin*]